# java.io.EOFException - ActiveMQ messaging broker

Tags: java, ssl, activemq-classic, eofexception

Here is the trace which is from startup.log (tomcat)

```
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:267)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Using below URL to connect broker:

```
failover:(ssl://{0}?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0)?maxReconnectAttempts=5

{0} - actual ip address to connect
```

Added the maxinactivity =0 because of below WARN, but getting this exception in log 5 times a day.

```
org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Channel was inactive for too (>30000) long: tcp://127.0.0.1:52659
```

whats wrong with my configurations? or should i investigate further in ssl or tcp connection transport layers? what is the reason behind the exception?

Answer (score 1):

The errors indicate that something is happening at the socket level that is causing a disconnect or half open socket to result and therefore the client is detect and reporting that it has disconnected.

There are many reasons why this could be happening, you might have a load balancer in the middle that is killing the client connection or the broker might be getting hung etc.  It doesn't appear to be a client issue, the client is telling you the connection failed.

Comment: Thanks Tim, So should i need to investigate more on socket level side, why connection drops or unhealthy broker? since i was not introducing load balancer still

Comment: Standard old school debugging, check everything and start eliminating them one by one.

Comment: Yah i tried this method, seems it continue showing this error in some point and when i remove the max inactivity param, it shows InactivityIOException as shown below. but the problem remains same.